# create list of all files in every subdirectories in bash

Tags: linux, bash, list, loops, subdirectory

I trying to write script in bash which will loop over all subdirectories, starring from given path, and will create list with md5 sums of all files in current directory.

I need something like `ls -R`, but I'm not sure how to start

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a very easy way of doing this with [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
find . -type f -exec md5 {} \;
```

The command finds all files (`-type f`), and executes the command md5 on each file (`-exec md5 {} \;`).

Comment: Nice, but it's looping over all files, even in hidden directories. Is there any way to loop only over normal directories?

Comment: You can exclude searching directories beging with a `.`, with `not -path "*/.*/*"` and files with beging with a `.` with `-not -name ".*"`

Comment: is there any reason to avoid using `-exec md5 {} +` instead?

Comment: Well that's a different question ;). But `md5 {} +` equates to `md5 file1 file2 file3 ...` and `md5 {} ;` equates to `md5 file1; md5 file2; md5 file3; ...`

Answer (score 1):

There is also a program called tree, but you can simulate it with only shell builtins:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=${1:-`pwd`}
SPACING=${2:-|}
cd $DIR
for x in * ; do
    [ -d "$DIR/$x" ] &&  echo "$SPACING\`-{$x" && $0 "$DIR/$x" "$SPACING  " || \
    echo "$SPACING $x : MD5=" && md5sum "$DIR/$x"
done
```

Note it requires a full path argument (or none for current directory)

Its not as fast as find (though there are plenty of ways to speed it up that make the code more complicated to follow), but gives a graphical representation of the tree structure.
You can modify it to not follow symlinks by adding- `&& [ ! -L "$DIR/$x" ]` or to only list directories: remove the `|| echo $SPACING $x`

Comment: How does this answer the question though?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Yeah, I missed the md5sum part on first read, but it is a shell script that loops all subdirectories... just need to add the md5sum on the file line after `echo "$SPACING $x"` something like `&& md5sum "$DIR/$x"` ... forgot to mention that it takes a full path argument too